# Mixing chains of "." and "->" operators

Tags: c++, c, pointers, nested, chaining

Having some concerns about the functionality of the member reference and pointer operators..

Take the following example:

```
struct ID{
    uint8_t index;
    bool active;
}

struct Square{
    struct ID shortID;
    struct BUDDY *bud;
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
};
```

And then I later return a pointer to a square.. 
 My question is: **Can I then modify members of ID and have the changes reflected in the nested struct?**

```
void function1()
{
    Square *someSquare = GetSquare(1);
    someSquare->shortID.index = 89; // Is this now reflected everywhere? OR was the shortID struct only modified in the scope of this funciton..
}

void function2()
{
    Square *someSquare = GetSquare(1);
    if ( someSquare->shortID.index != 89 )
    {
        // Dang...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the concise answers, yes the GetSquare function returns a pointer to the specified index of an array of squares. Like so:

```
Square* GetSquare( uint8_t index )
{
    return &squares[index];  
}
```

So the instance should be the same every time, as the "squares" array is allocated once on object creation. So thank you for your insight my problem must be elsewhere in my code :)

Comment: It completely depends on what `GetSquare` does. Does it return a different instance each time, or the same one?

Comment: -1 please *copy and paste real code*. for the above pretend code, at least fix the indentation and add the requisite semicolons. you're leaving people guessing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes because someSquare is a `Square*`
the `->` operator is like a `(*varname).` .
So it is the content of the pointer and you get the type `Square`.
Then you can just modify the variable with `.` , because its a struct and all variables are public not like it could be in classes.

The Changes you made in function1 can be seen in function2 if the `GetSquare` returns the same object that could be the case if your `GetSquare` looks like this.

```
Square * GetSquare(int i)
{
    static Square * pSquare = 0;
    if (pSquare)
        pSquare = malloc(sizeof(static Square));
    return pSquare;
}
```

or for global variables like this

```
static Square pSquare ;

Square * GetSquare(int i)
{
    return &pSquare;
}
```

Comment: It's still in the scope of the function if he isn't using a global instance...he may be just be creating new instances each time.

Answer (score 1):

If the Square pointer in function1 points to the same Square as the Square pointer in function2 then yes, you will see the value set in function1 in function2 (provided the functions are called in that sequence).

If the pointers point to different instances you will not see the value though.

As pointed out by juanchopanza, it all depends on what your GetSquare function does. Please post the definition of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be in the scope because you are not using any form of global instance. I don't know what getSquare actually does, but I assume it instantiates the Square class and returns the instance...

Comment: You can't say that from the code posted. `GetSquare(1)` could be returning a pointer to the same instance.

Comment: I know, but i'm just saying. I think the first arg is just to set a value, or pull from a DB...we don't know and whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `someSquare->someID.index` is just like accessing `someSquare->x` - in both cases it modifies the object pointed to by `someSquare` (in the first case it's modifying a sub-object).

Answer (score 0):

Yes , if the GetSquare(1) returns the same instance, then the change should be reflected in function2() also.
If you want to be sure that the instance returned is same , try to print the value of pointer someSquare by this statement:

```
printf("Value of pointer: %p \n",someSquare);
```

If this value is same that it means they are same instances and the change should be reflected in function2().

Also GetSquare should be a global function outside of any class, or static function. If it is instance function, then it will access different arrays of class "Square" for different class objects.

Other than that, I could not give another opinion based on code available.